# Place to run Kafka MirrorMaker

Tags: apache-kafka

It seems to be a good practice to run Kafka MirrorMaker in the target cluster. I can't really find the reasoning for doing so. What is the problem with running MirrorMaker in the source cluster?

Any hints appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MirrorMaker is a consumer as well as a producer, it's simply encouraged to poll from the remote cluster rather than produce into one.

Reasons include latency and time outs, but mostly if you deployed in the source region, and you consumed offsets, and produce requests fail or time out, then you'll potentially lose or duplicate messages. Since those are network issues, it's better for the consumer not to have "immediate proximity" to the source where it's almost always likely to succeed in consuming